# Could not connect to marklogic using marklogic-jena api

Tags: java, marklogic, semantics, marklogic-9

Code Used to connect is as below

```
DigestAuthContext dcf=  new DatabaseClientFactory.DigestAuthContext("admin", "admin");
         DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(
                "localhost", 8000, "GraphTest",dcf);
        MarkLogicDatasetGraph dg = MarkLogicDatasetGraphFactory.createDatasetGraph(client);


String queryString = "SELECT ?person " +
            "WHERE { ?person <http://schema.test.com/ns/place#livesin> < https://data.test.com/loc-structure/London#this>}";

QueryExecution eq = QueryExecutionFactory.create(queryString,dg.toDataset());
    ResultSet results = eq.execSelect();
    while(results.hasNext()) {
        QuerySolution qs = results.next();
              }
```

Jar used: marklogic-client-api-4.0.3 and marklogic-jena-3.0.5
Error:

> - The type org.apache.jena.query.Dataset cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from      required .class files
>
>   - The method toDataset() from the type MarkLogicDatasetGraph refers to the missing type Dataset

Comment: You should properly wrap your code snippet and error logs from descriptive text.

Comment: Did you also include jars from Jena itself? Or just the two you mention above?

Comment: i had some old version of jars after updating to latest jar versions  Issue resolved